# Extending ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods

I'm struggling with the ExpandoObject.

I created the extension method for ExpandoObject as shown in the first class however, `obj.HasProperty` throws an error *''System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'HasProperty''*

For a test, I created an extension method for the string with the second class.  In this case, `name.HasB()` works as expected however, `obj.Name.HasB()` throws the same error as above.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
public static class ExpandoExtentions {
    public static bool HasProperty(this ExpandoObject obj, string property) =>
        (obj as IDictionary<string, object>).ContainsKey(property);
}

public static class StringExtensions {
    public static bool HasB(this string s) => s.ToLower().Contains("b");
}

public class ExpandoTest {
      public static void Main() {

        string name = "Bob";

        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.Name = name;


        // Both objects return "... String"
        Console.WriteLine($"name is a {name.GetType().Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"obj.Name is a {obj.Name.GetType().Name}");

        // Works as expected
        Console.WriteLine($"name has a b: {name.HasB()}");

        // Throws Error
        Console.WriteLine($"obj.Name has a b: {obj.Name.HasB()}");

        // Throws Error
        Console.WriteLine($"obj has a Name: {obj.HasProperty("Name")}");
    }
}
```